# Point2D Double doesn't store a double

Tags: java, floating-point, double

So I'm working on a triangle class and I wanted to use the Point2D.Double to store points with high percision.

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double;

public class Triangle {

private Double pointOne = new Double();
private Double pointTwo = new Double();
private Double pointThree = new Double();
private final float PERCISION = 0.009f;

public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
{
    pointOne.x = x1;
    pointOne.y = y1;
    pointOne.setLocation(x2, y2);
    pointOne.setLocation(x3, y3);

}

public Double getPointOne() 
{
    return pointOne;
}

public Double getPointTwo() 
{
    return pointTwo;
}

public Double getPointThree() 
{
    return pointThree;
}
```

However when I test it in main and type in the code below, it prints out the coordinates but with a very low precision. I tried using floats but it always ends with the same result.

```
    Triangle tri = new Triangle( 0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0008, 0.0000, 0.0000, 2.0000);

    System.out.println("Point 1 coordinates: (" + tri.getPointOne().getX() + ", " + tri.getPointOne().getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Point 2 coordinates: (" + tri.getPointTwo().getX() + ", " + tri.getPointTwo().getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Point 3 coordinates: (" + tri.getPointThree().getX() + ", " + tri.getPointThree().getY() + ")");
```

Here is what it prints out just in case you need it.

Point 1 coordinates: (0.0, 2.0)

Point 2 coordinates: (0.0, 0.0)

Point 3 coordinates: (0.0, 0.0)

Ideally This is what I would want it to print out.

Point 1 coordinates: (0.0000, 2.0008)

Point 2 coordinates: (0.0000, 0.0000)

Point 3 coordinates: (0.0000, 0.0000)

Comment: Google for "how to format numbers in Java". 0.0 and 0.0000 are the same mathematical number. A double stores that. It doesn't store a way to format a number.

Comment: Also, fix your code: you never initialize pointTwo and pointThree, and you initialize poinOne three time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for custom decimal formating

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Edit : I've misread your question ! Forget what I said about primitives but you may need to perform some formatting

Comment: Ok but heres something I do not understand when I just type in this:

    Double point = new Double();
    point.x = 0.0000;
    point.y = 2.0008;
    System.out.println(point.x);
    System.out.println(point.y);
It prints out 2.0008 instead of just 2.0, I don't understand the different between my class and just typing that out and it is confusing me why one prints out differently than the other.

Comment: @mrpk Read my second comment, under your question.